# How to find multiple dot with space character before first dots using REGEX

Tags: regex

```
#^.[\S]+\.[\S]+\.(.*)$
```

I have used this regex to find multiple dot, but if my string contains white-space before first dot  then it is not working

```
^.[\S]+\.[\S]+\.(.*)$
```

> I expect that the regex should find this value

```
adajda9a b0a09.haa.ajada

teast.php.tasd

madnadak.ajada.a.jjhjhh

adjahdja.dfajha.ada.adjahdaj..jajjjjjhjha....dahhhhhbbja...

madkaja.adhakjda.sjjj

sadada.asdaa.jadfajk jadajda ajdhajda  ada- 0(i09d0a9 )_) aciai

aadhadka.adad.akdjajdka0sd009999a.o999

adajda9a b0a09.haa.ajada
```

[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear... Could you give for an example of `input` your expected `output`?

Comment: @Allan
Need the Regex that match's this string
**adajda9a b0a09.haa.ajada**

Comment: When you say string is it only one line or the whole string?

Comment: It is one line only

Comment: Can you have multiple space characters in the string like: `adajda9a b0a09.haa.ajada` or `adajda9a b0a09.ha a.ajad a`?

Comment: Did our answers solve your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to match strings that have at least two dots, then why not just use this:

```
^.*\..*\..*$
```

### Demo

You could also write this using a lookahead:

```
^(?=.*\..*\.).*$
```

Comment: It is very unclear about what OP wants but from what the title says it looks like he needs to have a space before the dots appear in the string

Comment: @Allan Not accoding to the sample data, which says that `teast.php.tasd` should match.

Comment: I thought it had to match that string as well, but in the comments he said it had to match only one string from his inputs... Anyway... If you have ideas/suggestions to improve my regex ;-) would love to hear them.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a regex that will match strings that have multiple dots in them and where there is only one space before the dots appear.

```
^[^.\s]* [^\s]*(?:\..*\..*)+$
```

**Demo:** https://regex101.com/r/UQksQK/4/

If you want to allow several spaces before the dots, use

```
^[^\.\s]* +.*(?:\..*\..*)+$
```

This will also match:

```
adajda9a     b0a09.haa.ajada.123
```

If you want to forbid the space character between the dots, change the regex into:

```
^[^.\s]* +[^\s]*(?:\.[^\s]*\.[^\s]*)+$
```

It will not match strings like (where you have spaces between the dots):

```
adajda9a b0a09.ha a.ajada.123
```

Answer (score 0):

Per comment to match line with space preceding first multiple dots:

```
^[^\.]* .*\..*\..*$
```

Test:

```
$ cat test.regexp
teast.php.tasd
madnadak.ajada.a.jjhjhh
adjahdja.dfajha.ada.adjahdaj..jajjjjjhjha....dahhhhhbbja...
madkaja.adhakjda.sjjj
sadada.asdaa.jadfajk jadajda ajdhajda  ada- 0(i09d0a9 )_) aciai
aadhadka.adad.akdjajdka0sd009999a.o999
adajda9a b0a09.haa.ajada

$ egrep "^[^\.]* .*\..*\..*$" test.regexp
adajda9a b0a09.haa.ajada
```